# Preserve formatting in code snippet area with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create my own code snippet area where the author can write pure html inside a `code` block which will be converted to text automatically. This works as demonstrated here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mtdrdvaw/2/

However, the line break of elements doesn't persist once converting them to text. 
I would like the formatting to remain the same after the HTML to text conversion.

Is this possible and how could I achieve this?

This is my code snippet markup:

```
<code class="code-snippet">
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test1</div>
  <div class="item">test2</div>
</code>
```

And here's the script:

```
var codeSnippets = document.getElementsByClassName('code-snippet'),
    length = codeSnippets.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

  var code = codeSnippets[i].innerHTML,
      node = document.createTextNode(code);

  codeSnippets[i].innerHTML = '';
  codeSnippets[i].appendChild(node);
}
```

**EDIT:** Since I was unclear, I've looked at `samp`, `pre` and `code` but none of them did what I wanted them to do. I want the area to use my own padding and look the way it is written in the code editor of the author. Using just `pre` for example gives it a ridiculous white space that I do not want.

Comment: @Oka I don't understand the downvote nor what your point is. I've looked at a number of options but none of them works the way I want them to since the formatting isn't what I want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
white-space: pre;
```

**Snippet**

```js
var codeSnippets = document.getElementsByClassName('code-snippet'),
    length = codeSnippets.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  
  var code = codeSnippets[i].innerHTML,
      node = document.createTextNode(code);
  
  codeSnippets[i].innerHTML = '';
  codeSnippets[i].appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.code-snippet {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: #15181F;
  color: white;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<code class="code-snippet">
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test1</div>
  <div class="item">test2</div>
</code>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgoe2ptf/**

Comment: Just what I was looking for, but is there a way to remove that ridiculous spacing that occurs? I want it to just use my own padding.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You have a line break on the top and spaces on the left. Please get rid of them using `trim()`.

Comment: Tried it, the issue is the line breaks between elements that doesn't get removed. And should I remove them, it will no longer line break and have an indent if there is one. Not sure if this is do-able, what do you think?

Comment: Noooo. I am saying the first ever line break.

Comment: Yes, I know. Trim() solves that issue, but the other two elements still has white space to the left, since trim only removes it from both ends of a string, not in between.

Comment: Use this: `var code = codeSnippets[i].innerHTML.trim()`.

Comment: I am.. I'll update the fiddle so you can see the problem. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/mtdrdvaw/2/

Comment: Managed to create a very, very hacky CSS solution so now it looks like I want it to at least. Thanks for your help in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't work with indent but it's ok, since I found a workaround.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Did you see the above commnet?

Comment: Yes, that's what I responded to.